# if logic and variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have multiple variables like `$soft0 , $soft1 , $soft2 , $soft3 , $soft4 , $soft5` and also like `$fo0 , $fo1 , $fo2 , $fo3 , $fo4 , $fo5` but if i want to apply a if condition here then it showing error. Code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=29; $i++) {
    $soft$i = str_replace(" ", "+", $fo$i); // this line showing an error
    $link_f_u = $html->find('h3', 0);
    $keyy = $link_f_u->plaintext;
    if ($soft$i==$keyy){
        continue;
    } else { 
        publish($soft$i);
    }
}
```

Any ideas to modify this code?

Comment: Why aren't you using an array?

Answer (score 3):

This will fix your error, but I would *highly* recommend you take a look at arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

```
for($i=0;$i<=29;$i++){
    $softVarName = "soft" . $i;
    $foVarName = "fo" . $i;

    $$softVarName = str_replace(" ", "+", $$foVarName);
    $link_f_u = $html->find('h3', 0);
    $keyy = $link_f_u->plaintext;
    if ($$softVarName==$keyy){
        continue;
    } else { 
        publish($$softVarName);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need double dollars on your references.

Comment: Gahh, remembered them in my test code, forgot in my answer. Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the issue.

```
for($i=0;$i<=29;$i++){
    ${'soft' . $i} = str_replace(" ", "+", ${'fo' . $i}); // this line showing an error
    $link_f_u = $html->find('h3', 0);
    $keyy = $link_f_u->plaintext;
    if (${'soft' . $i} == $keyy){
        continue;
    } else { 
        publish(${'soft' . $i});
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm certain that `$soft{$i}` will not work. See: `$soft1 = "test"; $i = 1; echo $soft{$i};` Will produce the error `Undefined variable: soft`

Comment: Yes, sorry. My mistake. I've updated the answer, now that should work.

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1 (best option):

change `$soft0 ... $soft10` to [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) looking like `$soft[0] .. $soft[10]`. You can then use `count()` in your for loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($soft);$i++){
    $soft[$i] = str_replace(" ", "+", $fo[$i]);
    $link_f_u = $html->find('h3', 0);
    $keyy = $link_f_u->plaintext;
    if ($soft[$i]==$keyy){
        continue;
    } else { 
        publish($soft[$i]);
    }
}
```

#### Option 2:

You can also use double dollar sign, however this is messy and can result in errors that are hard to catch.

```
$soft_name = 'soft'.$i;
$fo_name = 'fo'.$i;
$$soft_name = str_replace(" ", "+", $$fo_name);
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `$soft{$i}` will not work. See: `$soft1 = "test"; $i = 1; echo $soft{$i};` Will produce the error `Undefined variable: soft`

Comment: @Supericy I saw it in the other answer. Was in the process of testing for myself. It doesn't work. I've removed it.